# 500 internal server error while using jQuery get() method

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to fetch data using the get() method of jQuery to fill dropdown, but I'm getting a 500 internal server error. My jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#cat').change(function(){            
        $.get("{{url('types')}}",{id:$(this).val()}, function(data){
            $('#subcat').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                $('#subcat').append("<option value='"+ element.ty_id +"'>" + element.ty_name + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The route is:

```
Route::get('types', function(){
    $cat_id = Input::get('id');
    $type = App\type::where('cat_id', $cat_id)->get();
    return Response::json($type);
});
```

The `sample.blade.php` file is:

```
<form method="#"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <label>Categories</label>
    <select class="form-group" id="cat" name="cat">
    @foreach($cat as $val)
        <option value="{{$val->cat_id}}">{{$val->cat_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select><br>

    <label>type</label>
    <select class="form-group" name="subcat" id="subcat">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the error you are having exactly?

Comment: 500 is a general error. Please check laravel.log file and see what 'exact' error you are getting and post that here

Comment: '500 internal server error' at console

Comment: [2016-04-20 11:33:05] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Input' not found' in /var/www/html/easyRestaurant/app/Http/routes.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Comment: yeas it is woring ,i just added 'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class, in config file

Comment: 200 means the request was fulfilled. Should also note that if you're using Laravel 5.0 or higher,  you should use Request facade. Input is not mentioned in the documentation from 5.0 on. It's not (officially) deprecated but the use of Request is encouraged.

Comment: ohk thanks, so i should use request class instead of input??

Comment: yeap its working thankq

Comment: I would use Request. There is no real difference in them but Request is what is referenced in the documentation.

Comment: you can simply add `\Input` or use `request()->input('id')` (laravel 5.1+)